# Unable to retrieve all array elements

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a script where i have defined two arrays. Now depending on the array name passed (as parameter), i want to process the same in the function below. Earlier, i wasn't even getting any element in variable 'ARRAY' until i used `${!}`

Now the problem is that when i am printing the array content (or the number of elements in that array), i am getting only the first element.

Any suggestions?

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

APP=$1

process_data() {
    ARRAY="${!1}"
    echo "No of array elements: ${#ARRAY[@]}"
    echo "Array content: ${ARRAY[@]}"
}


ORADATA=(
"oraserver/content:abcDaily/ORAServer/"
"oraserver/w3s-ix86:abcDaily/ORAServer/"
)

SQLDATA=(
"sqlserver/content:abcDaily/SQLServer/"
"sqlserver/w3s-ix86:abcDaily/SQLServer/"
)

process_data ${APP[@]}
```

Command:

```
-bash-2.05b$ ./testarray.sh ORADATA
```

Output:

```
No of array elements: 1
Array content: oraserver/content:abcDaily/ORAServer/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version without eval (so it handles shell metacharacters in the array values properly):

```
#!/bin/bash

APP=$1

process_data() {
    ARRAYVAR="$1[@]"   # This just textually appends "[@]" to $1
    ARRAY=("${!ARRAYVAR}")   # Use indirect expansion to get contents of array, store as new array
    echo "No of array elements: ${#ARRAY[@]}"
    echo "Array content: ${ARRAY[@]}"
}


ORADATA=(
"oraserver/content:abcDaily/ORAServer/"
"oraserver/w3s-ix86:abcDaily/ORAServer/"
)

SQLDATA=(
"sqlserver/content:abcDaily/SQLServer/"
"sqlserver/w3s-ix86:abcDaily/SQLServer/"
)

process_data $APP   # Note that APP is not an array, so the [@] bit was irrelevant
```

Example:

```
$ ./testarray.sh ORADATA
No of array elements: 2
Array content: oraserver/content:abcDaily/ORAServer/ oraserver/w3s-ix86:abcDaily/ORAServer/
```

Comment: It works too. :) Thanks for the comments Gordon. They were quite helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your modified script that works (with the help of dreaded `eval`):

```
#!/bin/bash

APP=$1

process_data() {
   ARRAY=( $(eval echo \${$1[@]}) )
   echo "No of array elements: ${#ARRAY[@]}"
   echo "Array content: ${ARRAY[@]}"
}

ORADATA=(
"oraserver/content:abcDaily/ORAServer/"
"oraserver/w3s-ix86:abcDaily/ORAServer/"
)

SQLDATA=(
"sqlserver/content:abcDaily/SQLServer/"
"sqlserver/w3s-ix86:abcDaily/SQLServer/"
)

process_data ${APP[@]}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
No of array elements: 2
Array content: oraserver/content:abcDaily/ORAServer/ oraserver/w3s-ix86:abcDaily/ORAServer/
```